# Adding a row for the sum of a field to Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-suit

I have an invoices app I would like to be able to display the total of the invoice in the admin panel at the bottom. (I'm using Django-suit)

[image]

Is there an easy way of doing this within Django?

e: Should something like this work?

```
class InvoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [InvoiceItemInline]
    list_display = ('description', 'date', 'status', 'invoice_amount')

    def invoice_amount(self, request):
        amount = InvoiceItem.objects.filter(invoice__id=request.id).values_list('price', flat=True)
        quantity = InvoiceItem.objects.filter(invoice__id=request.id).values_list('quantity', flat=True)
        total_current = amount(float) * quantity(float)
        total_amount = sum(total_current)
        return total_amount
```

Answer (score 0):

you're on the right track except that `list_display` only applies to the page where all invoices are listed, you won't see that when editing a specific invoice

To see it while editing a specific invoice I think you need to override the `change_view` method, which is called as a view function:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view

Something like this:

```
class InvoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [InvoiceItemInline]
    list_display = ('description', 'date', 'status', 'invoice_amount')

    # You need to customise the template to make use of the new context var
    change_form_template = 'admin/myapp/extras/mymodelname_change_form.html'

    def _invoice_amount(self, invoice_id):
        # define our own method to serve both cases
        order_values = InvoiceItem.objects.filter(invoice__id=invoice_id).values_list(
            'price', 'quantity', flat=True)
        return reduce(
            lambda total, (price, qty): total + (price * qty),
            order_values,
            0
        )

    def invoice_amount(self, instance):
        # provides order totals for invoices list view
        return self._invoice_amount(instance.pk)

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        # provides order total on invoice change view
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        extra_context['order_total'] = self._invoice_amount(object_id)
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id,
            form_url, extra_context=extra_context)
```

note you need to override the change form template too to make use of the `order_total` variable we're sending back in `extra_context`